# PHP Shopping Basket Issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently trying to implement a shopping basket function to my personal website but seem to be struggling. I have added the link from my products page and that is passing the 'ID' information over as it should however whenever I add a product to my basket and it takes me to my shopping basket page it always displays 'You have no items in your shopping basket'. Here is my script, any help on the issue would be much appreciated. This is my first attempt and my php skills in this area are limited, with that in mind I do apologize if there is a very simple solution.

```
    <?php
    if ($_Get[action]=="add") {
$radio_id=$_Get[radio_id];
$_Session[$radio_id]++;
    }

    if($_SESSION[$radio_id]) { 
    echo "<table border=\"1\" padding=\"3\" width=\"40%\">"; 

    foreach($_SESSION[$radio_id] as $radio_id => $quantity) { 

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM radios WHERE              radio_id=".$_GET[radio_id]) or die( mysqli_error($link));
    $array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    //echo "<p>Manufacturer: " . $array[manufacturer] . "<br>";
    //echo "Model: " . $array[model] . "<br>";
    //echo "Price: " . $array[price] . "<br>";
    //echo "Description: " . $array[description] . "</p>";

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    list($array[model], $array[manufacturer], $array[description], $array[price]) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    $line_cost = $array[price] * $quantity;
    $total = $total + $line_cost;

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\">$name</td>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\">$quantity <a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=remove&id=$product_id\">X</a></td>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\">$line_cost</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"right\">Total</td>";
    echo "<td align=\"right\">$total</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td colspan=\"3\" align=\"right\"><a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=empty\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?');\">Empty Cart</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
    echo "</table>";
    }

    else{
    echo "You have no items in your shopping cart.";
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Just so you know, `$_Get` must be in uppercase `$_GET` which is a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Comment: It's questions like these, that always opens up a "can of worms".

Answer (score 1):

Few points to be corrected:

- $_Get should be `$_GET`.
- $_Session should be `$_SESSION`.

Your facing this problem because of incorrect syntax for session. Change $_Session to `$_SESSION` on line number four. Also use `session_start()` at beginning of your page, if you haven't started your session .

**Updated code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_GET['action']=="add") {
$radio_id=$_GET['radio_id'];
$_SESSION[$radio_id]++;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Ive used session start and have updated what you suggested. I am now getting the error, Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /ncooney2.bimserver2.com/finalyearproject1/basket.php on line 35. Which is the Foreach part of my code.

Comment: Whatever you have supplied for `foreach` is not in array format.So try checking it using `in_array` function..

Comment: Sorry to be an absolute pain, but is there anyway you could explain your last point to me in a little more detail?

Comment: Array ( [cart] => 1 [$radio_id] => 1 ) That's the result.

Comment: Do `print_r($_SESSION[$radio_id]);` and temme the result

Comment: After changing that, it now isnt displaying the session information.

Comment: So there is the error..your passing empty array to `foreach` loop..so you need to resolve that..